# Mapping image in react but not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have trouble, i want to creat real time seats for movie ticket, but when i map my image for seat condition, the image not render. when i open the page by refreshing the page, the image rendered, but when i move to the page where have seat map with this.props.history.push the seats map not render.
this is my code

this is the seats component :

```
function Index({id, key}) {
    const state = useSelector(state => state.movie)
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false)
    const [sold, setSold] = useState([])

    
    const handleSelect=(id)=>{
        if(selected){
            setSelected(false)
        }else{
            setSelected(true)
        }
        console.log(id);
    }
    console.log(state.movie);
    return (
        <div className="ord-icon-book">
            <div className="ord-icon-book-item"   name='seat'id={id} key={key}>
                <img src={'http://localhost:6400/image/Rectangle%20540.png'} alt="A4" name='A4' placeholder='seat'/>
            </div>
            <div className="ord-icon-book-item"  name='seat'id={id} key={key}>
                <img src={'http://localhost:6400/image/Rectangle%20443.png'} alt="A3" name='A3' />
            </div>

            {selected ?
            <div className="ord-icon-book-item"  id='selected' onClick={()=>handleSelect(id)} id={id} key={key}>
                <img src={'http://localhost:6400/image/Rectangle%20469.png'} alt="A1" name='A1' />
            </div> :
            <div className="ord-icon-book-item" id='available' onClick={()=>handleSelect(id)} id={id} key={key}>
                <img src={'http://localhost:6400/image/Rectangle%20438.png'} alt="A2" name='A2' />
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Index
```

and this where i map the component :

```
import Seats from './seats'


 componentDidMount(){
        let i;
     for(i=0; i< 14; i ++){
           this.state.seats.push(i)
        }
        let seat = document.getElementByClass
        console.log(this.state.seats);
    }

<div className="ord-spoting">
<div className="ord-spot-left">
    {this.state.seats.map((id, index)=>{
     return  <Seats id={id} key={index}/>
     })}
</div>
<div className="ord-spot-left">
    {this.state.seats.map((i,k)=>{
     <Seats /> 
    })}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set an image like this in react, or plain html for that matter. You want to use a relative path in case of plain HTML

like so:

`<img src='./image/Rectangle540.png' alt="A1" name='A1' />`

Since you're using React, you cannot set sources directly. You have to import the image asset first.

like so:

```
import myRectancle from "./image/Rectangle540.png";
```

and then, in the JSX, use it like this:

```
<img src={myRectangle} alt="A1" name='A1' />
```

Make sure the image paths are correct, depending on your project folder structure.

Comment: thanks for answering @Jay Pillai, but it still not work,  :/ ,
the image still not render..

Comment: @ADWisnuPrasetio can you post your code in a codesandbox? use codesandbox.io . Also, it looks like you're rendering an Index component, not a Seats component in your first code snippet.

Comment: can you check here please 
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-pine-jfvbx?file=/src/Order.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-http-dtdxd?file=/src/seats.js take a look here. I removed a lot of irrelavant code for this particular issue but it works. Make sure you're setting the styles properly so you can see the rendered image and divs. Also, import and export the correct component. You were exporting 'Index' from Seats.js and importing Seats from this file, which does not exist

Comment: oke, how if i want multiple the image to 30?
coz in my code  i creat some image to seat location, and multiple it to 98 item, like in my code..,  can i push the image to array, and map it to page?

Comment: Sorry, your comment isn't very clear and i'm not sure what you're asking. If you're asking how to render multiple images like this, and the source needs to be different each time, look into dynamic imports and lazy loading in react. This is out of scope of the original question now. Accept the answer if it solved your initial problem.

Comment: sorry Jay, your answer not solve my problem, its not about 'cant rendering an image', but about 'my map of image not render except when i reload my page,' like my code share to you...  but thank you very much for your answer and your help...

Comment: @ADWisnuPrasetio https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-http-dtdxd?file=/src/App.js i modified it again, it works even with map

Comment: Thanks you Jay, i found my problem, in my case i do like get some item from back end in useEffect and it work solve my problem.

but i think your code in codesandbox work too, so i think it will help other peopple if they have same issue like this. thank you very much for yor help Jay ...

Comment: @ADWisnuPrasetio glad you found your issue, Wisnu! As for the initial question asked, the problem was that you were not importing your image assets properly so the answer still applies.